# Is it possible to make website that is using the cloudflare dns proxy work during cloudflare outage?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, reverse-proxy, cloudflare, infrastructure

I thought about setting up a small server with nginx reverse proxy, adding its IP as A dns without cloudflare dns proxy next to main A record with CF dns proxy enabled, so it will be a backup option if the CF dns will go down. Is it possible to do that? Are there other solutions for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Honestly, Cloudflare being down is probably the least of your worries. If Cloudflare is down, the rest of the world is probably not concerned with getting to your website.

Comment: They had 30 minutes downtime month ago or so. I know, it happens very rarely, but still...

Comment: It has 30 minutes downtime last month - and that is the ONLY downtime I can remember. Over years. So, yes, this likely is the smallest of your problems.

Comment: Also, alternative DIY solutions are way more likely to fail, causing more downtime.

Answer (score 1):

How will this have better availability than a CDN with 150 points of presence globally? And whose solution requires they manage your DNS?

Your business continuity plan could include alternate authoritative DNS outside of Cloudflare. Changing DNS could bypass CDN or switch to a different one. Beware, DNS will likely be cached for longer than typical outage duration of a major CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I know some device that dynamicly manage the DNS zone and it work as when it detect a fail it switch to a backup route for all DNS query.

When the fail is over it return the query to the standard result it’s supposed to have.

I don’t know if they can be used with cloudflare.

They do have low domain TTL set for the device to work and as told they manage the DNS zone.

The one I know about was manufactured by elfiq, but I guess it’s not the only business that do such appliance.